# creating uitableview programmatically in swift not loading

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I'm trying to create a uitableview programmatically in swift but is not loading here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    var tableView: UITableView  =   UITableView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate      =   self
        tableView.dataSource    =   self
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
    }
```

Any of you knows what I'm missing or what is wrong with my code?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to use the proper initializer for the table view. Use the one that specifies its type and frame.

Comment: @rmaddy can you post and example?

Answer (score 10):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
}
```

> tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)

This line of code will set the frame of your `tableview`, with default `UITableViewStyle` as well.

Comment: `tableView.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` will also do.
If you don't set the frame, there won't be any display even if everything else is correct in your UITableView code.

Answer (score 1):

late but can help others, you have to add :

```
tableView.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: This gives error. Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'translateAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints' !!

Comment: `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView) 
}
```

You can give customize frame as: CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)
Here width and height refers to desired tableview width & height

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 3.x

```
//MARK: Create TableView

func createTableView()   -> Void {

    print("Create Table View.")
    if self.tblView == nil{
        self.tblView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, style: .plain)
        self.tblView.delegate = self
        self.tblView.dataSource = self
        self.tblView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.view.addSubview(self.tblView)
    }
    else{
        print("Table view already has been assigned.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before setting up  delegates, use

```
tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
```

It will work properly

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 3:

```
var tableView: UITableView  =   UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, style: .plain)
      tableView.delegate = self
      tableView.dataSource = self
      tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
       self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 3x

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```